# How to transpose memsql data rows into columns

Tags: singlestore

I'm looking to reorder some data, here's the current set up

```
Account  | Delay | Value | 
ACCOUNT1 | 0     | 5     |
ACCOUNT1 | 100   | 10    |
ACCOUNT1 | 200   | 10    |
ACCOUNT1 | 0     | 8     |
ACCOUNT1 | 100   | 12    |
ACCOUNT1 | 200   | 5     |
ACCOUNT1 | 0     | 10    |
ACCOUNT1 | 100   | 15    |
ACCOUNT1 | 200   | 20    |
ACCOUNT2 | 0     | 30    |
ACCOUNT2 | 100   | 40    |
ACCOUNT2 | 200   | 25    |
```

and then output it as a sum of the value by account/delay combo, like the below

```
     | 0    | 100   | 200
ACCOUNT1 | 23   | 37    | 35
ACCOUNT2 | 30   | 40    | 25
```

I'd thought this could be done with MEMSQL Cases (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) and I can't get it to work

```
SELECT ACCOUNT,
    CASE WHEN DELAY_IN_MILLIS = '0' THEN sum(VALUE) END "0",
    CASE WHEN DELAY_IN_MILLIS = '100' THEN sum(VALUE) END "100",
    CASE WHEN DELAY_IN_MILLIS = '200' THEN sum(VALUE) END "200",
END AS text
FROM TABLE
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
sum(if(DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 0, VALUE, 0)),
sum(if(DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 100, VALUE, 0)),
...
```